# Excel Formula Help: If Reference Cell = 1, value of Cell1 = "X", If Reference Cell = 2, value of Cell1 = ""

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a cell in my Excel Workbook - Range("D5") - that gets its values by selecting from a dropdown list. The choices are 1 or 2.

If the choice is 1, I need to set Range("J13").value = "X".

If the choice is 2, I need to set Range("L13").value = "X".

I need 2 formulas for both ("J13") and ("L13") that will set the value based on the 2 conditions, Range("D5") being 1 or 2.

Can anyone assist me with this? I don't have much experience in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cell: `J13`

```
=IF(D5 = 1, "X", "")
```

For cell: `L13`

```
=IF(D5 = 2, "X", "")
```

Comment: When I try to set the formula on workbook open `range("J13:K13").Formula = "=IF(D5=1,"X","""")"` the **X** gets flagged with `Compile error: Expected: end of statement`.

Comment: I get the same thing with `range("J13:K13").Formula = "=IF(D5=1,"X","")"`

Comment: You need double quotes around the `X` i.e. `Range("J13:K13").Formula = "=IF(D5=1,""X"","""")"`

Comment: Thanks Alex, that solved it! I really should have thought to try that :/ Been a long week.

Comment: Good stuff. We got there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simple...put this in  J13

```
=IF(D5=1,"X","")
```

and this in L13

```
=IF(D5=2,"X","")
```

Comment: When I try to set the formula on workbook open `range("J13:K13").Formula = "=IF(D5=1,"X","""")"` the **X** gets flagged with `Compile error: Expected: end of statement`.

Comment: You have too many quotes there...also if you are going to drag this formula down, to refer to that D5 cell, it has to be named, so that its a constant.....in top left you should see D5 when you click on d5, then change that to aNewName or whatever you want, then you can refer to it in the formula....IF(myNewName=1,"X","")  then you can copy this forumal to anywhere, and it will work  http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000704.htm

Comment: I don't understand? Why do I need to rename cell D5 to use it in an IF statement? `range("J13:K13").Formula = "=IF(D5=1,"X","")"` is giving me the same issue with the **X** getting flagged.

Comment: You dont need to rename it, but if you want to refer to the same cell over and over again, in a range of cells, you do.....otherwise it will just change your formula to be D6=1 D7=1 D8=1 as you drag it down.....whereas if you name it it stays referncing the D5

Comment: What do you mean _drag it down_? I'm setting the formula in vba code when the workbook opens, not in the formula bar.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Kyle. Alex got me squared away.